# JavaScript canvas and mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, position, mouse

I'm trying to make a drawing board in HTML5 with JavaScript, but the tools (like pencil, brush etc..) position is different unlike I thought.

I found it is different because of bitmap(?) so I'm trying to fix it from other answers which persons already asked, but I failed..

How to find the correct position of the mouse?

[image: images]

Here is my HTML code (I use bootstrap)

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <canvas id="c" width="900" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

This is js (pencil code is not mine, I found on the internet)

```
var el = document.getElementById('c'); //캔버스
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');  //붓

function pencil () {
    var pos = getMousePos(el, e);

    el.onmousedown = function() {
      isDrawing = true;
      ctx.moveTo(pos.X, pos.Y);
    };

    el.onmousemove = function() {
      if (isDrawing) {
        ctx.lineTo(pos.X, pos.Y);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    };

    el.onmouseup = function() {
      isDrawing = false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the getMousePos function [here](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/) and it looked like it would work with what you're doing.  But, it accepts an argument`e` (an event) that won't be defined where you were using it.  Try moving the call to `getMousePos` inside the event handler where the event is defined.

Also, `isDrawing` wasn't defined.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');  //붓
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";

function pencil () {
  var isDrawing = false;

  el.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(el, e);
    isDrawing = true;
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  };

  el.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(el, e);
    if (isDrawing) {
      ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };

  el.onmouseup = function() {
    isDrawing = false;
  };
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

pencil()
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <canvas id="c" width="900" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your diagram earlier and didn't find that problem with your code.  Can you elaborate on why you are getting the wrong position?  Does it have to do with the mouse cursor you're using?

Comment: Thank you!! it works very well!!! I just thought 'var pos = var pos = getMousePos(el, e);' code is under the function name, up on the 'el.onmousedown = function(e)'... can you explain why this 'var pos~~~' line should be in all onmouse function..?

Comment: @wendykr Because you're listening for mouse events and getting the position from the event, but the event get's passed to the handler so it isn't defined outside of `onmouse*`.  Event handlers are automatically called with the event as an argument (`e` in my code).

Comment: Ah, I understand. thank you so much!!!! Now i can fix other drawing tools. thanks again :)